# Linq dynamic select casting issue

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, casting

I want to run a query to get a string array of distinct "logName" items for a logType.  The following works great:

```
Dim stringArray() As String = (From item In dc.Vw_Logs 
    Where item.LogType = [Passed in logType] 
    Select item.LogName Distinct).ToArray()
```

However, this only works when a specific LogType is set.  I would like the logType clause to be optional.  To try and achieve this I have rewritten the query:

```
Dim q = From item In dc.Vw_Logs Distinct
If not logType is nothing Then 
    q = q.Where(Function(item) item.LogType = logType)
End If
q.Select(Function(item) item.LogName)
Dim stringArray() As String = q.ToArray()
```

With this I get the following error:

```
Value of type '1-dimensional array of Vw_Log' cannot be converted 
to '1-dimensional array of String'
```

What is the best way to get round this?  I would like to avoid iterating each item and casting.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because q is not strings but the type contained in dc.Vw_Logs.

I don't do much programming in VB anymore but this should get you close.

```
Dim q = From item In dc 
        Where (logType Is Nothing Or item.LogType = logType) 
        Select item.LogName Distinct


logType Is Nothing Or item.LogType = logType
```

If logType has a value, you will get the items that match; otherwise, you will get all of the items.

Comment: This wont work because if the logType (passed into the select method) is nothing, then this will result in no matches (I want all matches in this case)

Comment: Jeremy just misread your logic, but he's fundamentally correct. The Where clause should just be (logType Is Nothing Or item.LogType = logType)

Comment: I think we have our wires crossed. The logType in the database will ALWAYS have a value.  However, the method that I am trying to make takes a string of "logType".  If this is null, I would like the linq query to simply not include a filter for the logType (thus getting across all log types).  If I use the suggested logic above, this will always return no results when the logType passed in to the method is null.

Comment: I just checked and it works! I did not know you could mix checks against both server variables and database values in a single linq where statement. Wow! That is great. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line

```
q.Select(Function(item) item.LogName)
```

doesn't change q, it simply discards the result of the select so that when you do

```
Dim stringArray() As String = q.ToArray()
```

You're trying to convert the original q (which is of type Vw_Log) to an array of strings. Replace the last two lines with this:

```
Dim stringArray() As String = q.Select(Function(item) item.LogName).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not reuse q. The first assignment is Vw_Log(), the second is String().

You can also combine the last two lines to avoid this.

Comment: Sorry - i can't seem to get the above comment to format any better!

Comment: This seems to result in an inner SQL select statement:

Dim qTyped = From item In dc.Vw_Log Distinct
If logType <> Nothing Then qTyped = qTyped.Where(Function(item) item.LogType = logType)
Dim q = qTyped.Select(Function(item) item.LogName).Distinct()